# How can I get the number of rows in an Excel pivot table for use outside the pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel of the form:

```
Country      Server   Status
Australia      AU1      1
               AU2      1
               AU3      4
New Zealand    NZ1      4
               NZ2      1
Germany        DE1      1
               DE2      4
               DE3      1
```

I would like to add some summary information above the table showing the number of rows and the number of rows that match certain criteria, e.g.:

```
Number of servers:        8
Servers with status 4:    3
```

How can I count the rows in the pivot table, either in total or matching criteria? I have researched using the GETPIVOTDATA function but not found a solution (see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GETPIVOTDATA-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular Count(), Counta() or Countif() functions.

[image]

```
B1 =COUNTA(B4:B2000)
B2 =COUNTIF(C4:C2000,4)
```

Comment: Gah, can't believe I overlooked the simplest approach! Thanks ;)

Comment: @KendallLister Oh, but the relief when you realize that it's not complicated, after all!